# cable gland for pre terminated ip camera cable

Tags: cables

Preamble: First time posting here. I'm a noob in electronics.

I'm installing an outdoor ip camera. I need to route the cables from the camera into a waterproof project box I got off Amazon. The camera has a 3/16" diameter cable that splits into three cables, each with its own pre-terminated connector (one for power, one for ethernet and one that has a reset button) - see attached image. I need to get those three connectors inside the project box and still be able to seal the hole around the 3/16" cable. The largest connector has a 3/4" diameter, so my plan is to drill a 3/4" hole in the project box to feed all three connectors into the box. Are there any diy "tricks to the trade" solutions out there for sealing around a cable who's diameter is narrower than the pre-terminated connector?

[image: IP Camera Cable]

Comment: Is it possible to open up the camera? You may well find that the cables are joined to the board using much smaller connectors than the ones on the other end.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Finbarr. I thought of that as well, but the camera is sealed waterproof, and I didn't want to open it up and break the seal. Plus the cable has three elements (ethernet, power and reset button), so I imagine there will be a complicated assortment of connections inside the camera.

Comment: A couple of suggestions: 1) Get an over-sized rubber cable gland, cut it half way across, put the cable in, then jam it into a hole in the case. 2) Cut a small slot in the case, where the case lid meets the body - it then only needs to be big enough for the cable - then seal it up with silicone sealant.

Comment: Thanks Simon B. Very helpful. I think I'll try you're idea #1. Wondering how to mark this question as "answered".

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Roxtec style gland entry system.  It splits in two to allow passage of large end terminations and then clamshells back over the cable.

Comment: Hey thanks @AlmostDone. I took a look at the Roxtec site. They make some pretty amazing stuff. But overkill for my application. But I get what you're saying, the clamshell style. I just can't seem to find a source for a single cheap version for home application.